# List data Disappears after pressing back Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, items

**Whenever I add an item to my least it adds to the list at the current state but when I reopen after pop context the item is no more there**
*How can I have the items in list permanently *[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkPKa.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOKMn.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G08vp.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m22Zg.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdFFf.png)

```
class Prabesh extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PrabeshState createState() => _PrabeshState();
}

class _PrabeshState extends State<Prabesh> {
  final List users = [
    'Ram',
    'Shyam',
    'Hari',
    'Paudel',
    'Pandey',
    'Sashwat',
    'Kismat',
  ];

  // ondlt(Key key) {
  //   for (int i = 0; i <= users.length; i++) {
  //     var a = users.elementAt(i);
  //     if (key == a.key) {
  //       users.removeAt(i);
  //     }
  //   }
  // }

  void onClk() {
    myDialog(BuildContext, context);
  }

  final myUser = TextEditingController();

  myDialog(BuildContext, context) {
    showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Add a user'),
            content: TextFormField(
              controller: myUser,
              maxLength: 20,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter Username',
              ),
            ),
            actions: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  child: Text('Cancel')),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (myUser.text.isEmpty) {
                      return Navigator.pop(context);
                    } else {
                      users.add(myUser.text);
                      return Navigator.pop(context);
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: Text('Add'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Prabesh'),
          leading: BackButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          ),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: users.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
              elevation: 10,
              child: ListTile(
                // key: Key(users[index]),
                //onLongPress: () => ondlt(key),
                onTap: () {},
                title: Text(users[index]),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.menu),
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  child: Text(users[index].substring(0, 1)),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () => onClk(),
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must save your data locally or on an online database.

For saving data on mobile storage you can use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite).

But for saving data on an online database you can use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) or you must develop a web server.